# Dismiss WKWebview when there is no network on performing an action in a web page

Tags: ios, swift4, wkwebview

I am loading a signup form in a `WKWebView` and when the user fills in the signup form and taps on the Sign-Up button, it will be taken to a Signup Success page.

How to catch the no network error, if the user loses network connectivity on tapping the Signup button?

The below code works if the user is not connected to the network before the signup form is loaded :

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
        if(error.localizedDescription == "The Internet connection appears to be offline.") {
               print("Network error")
               self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
               let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Network", message: "No network, please check your internet connection and try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                   alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK".localisedString(), style: .default, handler: nil))
                   let topC = AppConstants.getRootController().topMostViewController()
               topC.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
               })
           }
        }
```

Comment: is there Network error message print in logs..?

Comment: Yes I am getting : 
`2019-12-10 11:41:48.083825+0530 Dubber[3158:1051832] Task <E6D0A152-C16F-4AB5-97D0-EBB284615E01>.<14> load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=50, NSUnderlyingError=0x28306ce10 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1009 "(null)"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You have dismissed current `ViewController` first and then you are trying to shoe `UIAlertController` , maybe that's why it's not working otherwise your code is correct
- Try to show `alert` first and then dismiss the current `ViewController` like below

  ```
  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFailProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
     if(error.localizedDescription == "The Internet connection appears to be offline.")
     {
      print("Network error")
      let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Network", message: "No network, please check your internet connection and try again.", preferredStyle: .alert)
      let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { ( _ ) in
      let topC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cal") as! cal
      self.present(topC, animated: true, completion: nil)
     }

  alert.addAction(ok)
  self.present(alert, animated: true) {
  self.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
   }
  }
  ```
- Try this code, this will work (what missing in the code were as below)

  1. `ok` AlertAction was not added in the `alert` AlertViewController
  2. `topC` was initialised but wasn't presented in `ok` action.

Comment: Still the same. When I tap on Signup with no network connected, nothing happens

Comment: Do you want to present the `rootViewController` after displaying `alert`???

Comment: Yes ,basically dismiss the wkwebview and present the view controller behind it.

Comment: I've edited the code and tested it , it will work just change your `rootViewController` code in `topC` ....if it works , kindly approve the answer.